# Finding Whether Two Numbers Share a Digit

Tags: java, while-loop, logic

I am working on this problem where I am supposed to use loops to find whether two numbers share a digit. The code I wrote does not return true if the shared digit is the first digit of a number. I can not find the bug in my code or any other solution. Please help!

```
public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
            if ((firstNumber < 10 || firstNumber > 99) || (secondNumber < 10 || secondNumber > 99)) {
                return false;
            }
    
            int testFirstNumber = firstNumber;
            int testSecondNumber = secondNumber;
    
            while (testFirstNumber != 0) {
                while (testSecondNumber != 0) {
                    if ((testFirstNumber % 10) == (testSecondNumber % 10)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    testSecondNumber /= 10;
                }
                testFirstNumber /= 10;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: You need to move the statement that initialises `testSecondNumber` inside the outer loop. At the moment you are only running through the inner loop once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reset testSecondNumber before the next testFirstNummber loop.
In your code, the inner loop is called only once, because testSecondNumber goes to 0 and is not reset.
The right solution is:

```
    public static boolean hasSharedDigit(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
    if ((firstNumber < 10 || firstNumber > 99) || (secondNumber < 10 || secondNumber > 99)) {
        return false;
    }

    int testFirstNumber = firstNumber;

    while (testFirstNumber != 0) {
        int testSecondNumber = secondNumber;
        while (testSecondNumber != 0) {
            if ((testFirstNumber % 10) == (testSecondNumber % 10)) {
                return true;
            }
            testSecondNumber /= 10;
        }
        testFirstNumber /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The right solution is without a `println` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that offered solution checks only 2-digit numbers so the performance is not the issue in this case and using nested loop should not have any serious impact.

However, if a common digit needs to be found for any integer numbers (not only positive), it would be better to use a small array to count digits in the first number and then verify if a digit from the 2nd number is present in this array without using nested loops.

```java
static boolean commonDigits(int xx, int yy) {
    // handle negative values
    int x = Math.abs(xx);
    int y = Math.abs(yy);
    int[] digits = new int[10];

    if (x == 0) { // handle 0
        digits[0]++;
    }
    while (x > 0) {
        digits[x % 10]++;
        x /= 10;
    }
    
    // check for 0 
    if (y == 0 && digits[0] > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    while (y > 0) {
        if (digits[y % 10] > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        y /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A shorter version based on converting a number into stream of characters via conversion to String may look like this:

```java
static boolean commonDigitsStream(int x, int y) {
    int[] digits = new int[10];
    
    Integer.toString(Math.abs(x))
        .chars()
        .map(i -> i - '0')
        .forEach(i -> digits[i]++);
    
    return Integer.toString(Math.abs(y))
        .chars()
        .map(i -> i - '0')
        .anyMatch(i -> digits[i] > 0);
}
```